Determining weak solution for Dirichlet problem
Let $D$ be the unit disk in the plane and let $\Omega= D\setminus\{0\}$. The Dirichlet problem
\begin{cases}
Δu = 1 & \text{in } \Omega \newline
u=0 & \text{on } \partial \Omega
\end{cases}
has no classical solution, but it has a unique weak solution in $H^1_0(\Omega)$. I am trying to determine the weak solution explicitly.
My attempt: 
Obviously, the solution to the PDE must be radially symmetric, so I use polar coordinates.
Therefore, it holds that $$\Omega=\{(r,\varphi):0<r<1, \text{ }0\leq\varphi<2\pi\}.$$
In polar coordinates, the Laplace operator is (using the radial symmetry of $u$)
$$Δu=\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial r^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}=\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\left(r\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\right).$$
Then, for $0<r<1$ the problem becomes
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\right)=r\Rightarrow r\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}=\frac{r^2}{2}+C_1\Rightarrow u(r)=\frac{r^2}{4}+C_1\ln(r)+C_2.$$
Now, $u(1)=0$ implies $C_2=-\frac{1}{4}$. To determine $C_1$, one need to ensure that $u$ remains finite as $r\to 0$. Since $\ln(r)\to -\infty$ for $r\to 0$, $C_1$ must be zero. Therefore, the explicit solution is
$$u(r)=\frac{r^2}{4}-\frac{1}{4} \text{ or } u(x)=\frac{|x|^2}{4}-\frac{1}{4}.$$
My question: 
Now, the following two questions arise:

This solution is twice continuously differentiable on $\Omega$. Doesn't this contradict the fact that there is no classical solution $u\in C^2(\Omega)\cap C(\bar\Omega)$?
Obviously, $u(0) = 0$ does not hold for $r = 0$. Does this not violate the boundary conditions? Or is the boundary condition to be understood in the sense of the trace in $L^2$?


What is the definition of weak solution that you are using?

@ArcticChar $u\in H_0^1(\Omega)$ is a weak solution if $\int_{\Omega}\sum_{i=1}^n u_{x_i}\varphi_{x_i}dx=\int_{\Omega}\varphi dx$ holds for every $\varphi\in H_0^1(\Omega)$

It seems that your $u(x) = \frac{1}{4} (|x|^2-1)$ is not in $H^1_0(\Omega)$.

@ArcticChar So the problem is that the function does not have a trace of zero? Is there another way to compute the solution explicitly?

Just take the definition that $H^1_0(\Omega)$ is the closure of $C^\infty_0(\Omega)$ under the $H^1$ norm. I did not check, but it seems that your $u$ cannot be approximated by functions in $C^\infty_0(\Omega)$.

Your $u$ is indeed in $H^1_0(\Omega)$. See the answer below.

The problem here is that the exterior of $\Omega$ is not "fat enough" near $0$. You can look up the Weiner criterion for an "if and only if" geometric condition telling you whether you can expect the solution to your Dirichlet problem to approach the boundary condition continuously from inside your domain.

Your function
$$u(x) = \frac{1}{4}(|x|^2-1).$$
is indeed in $H^1_0(\Omega)$. Instead of checking it directly, lets do the following.
Let $\epsilon \in (0,1)$, $A_\epsilon = \Omega\setminus B_\epsilon(0)$ be the annulus. Then the following Dirichlet problem
$$\begin{cases} \Delta u = 1 &\text{ in } A_\epsilon \\ u = 0 &\text{ on } \partial A_\epsilon\end{cases}$$
has a solution (found similarly as you did)
$$ u_\epsilon = \frac{1}{4} (|x|^2-1) + \frac{1-\epsilon^2}{4 \ln \epsilon} \ln |x|.$$
Note that $u_\epsilon \in H^1_0(A_\epsilon)$. Extending by $0$, we may consider  $u_\epsilon \in H^1_0 (\Omega)$. Now we show that $u_\epsilon$ converges to $u$ in $H^1_0(\Omega)$. It suffices to check that
$$ \int_{A_\epsilon} |g_\epsilon|^2 + |\nabla g_\epsilon |^2 \to 0$$
as $\epsilon\to 0$, where $g_\epsilon(x) = \ln |x|/\ln \epsilon$. We check only the latter one:
\begin{align} \int_{A_\epsilon} |\nabla g_\epsilon|^2 = \frac{2\pi}{(\ln \epsilon)^2} \int_\epsilon^1 \frac{1}{r^2} rdr = \frac{2\pi}{|\ln \epsilon|} \to 0
\end{align}
Since $u$ satisfies $\Delta u=1$ strongly in $\Omega$, it also satisfies $\Delta u=1$ weakly. Hence $u$ is a weak solution to the Dirichlet problem. However it is not a strong solution to the problem, since the boundary condition is not satisfied.
